# A fencing problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

So the problem is:

> I have bought a fence 30 meters long and I need to put it around three
>   of my rectangular fields sides. How long should be each of the field
>   sides, to create the biggest possible field size?

My field sides are $a$ and $b$, the perimeter of the three sides is $2a + b = 30$ and the size of the field is $a\times b$. I don't know how to solve this problem, but I think I should use derivatives and get the value of the tangent line to the parabola of the $a$ or $b$ graph. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $2a+b=30$, you know that $b=30-2a$. That means that the size of the field can be written in terms of $a$ alone:
$$S(a) = ab = a(30-2a) = 30a-2a^2.$$

Now, the side of the field can be as little as $0$, and as large as $15$ (since you only have 30 meters).

So you want to find the maximum of the function $S(a)$, with $0\leq a \leq 30$. This is an optimization problem, which can be solved by (i) finding the critical points; (ii) comparing the value of the function at the critical points and the end points of the relevant interval.

Answer (score 0):

Use $2a+b=30$ to get $b=30-2a$.  Substitute that back in to the area formula to obtain $f(a)=a(30-2a)=30a-2a^2$.  If you want you can differentiate that and find the maximum by finding the zeroes of the derivative.